# VBA cross-worksheet color coded matching within cells that have a value

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on an excel tool for almost a week now and as I have almost made it to the end I found myself facing an issue I currently am not able to resolve.

On one sheet in my workbook I have something like this:

[image: What I have in Sheet1]

Now I want to color code this (fill out the cells with colors) using sheet2 to match it. So you get an idea, here's sheet2:

[image: Matching sheet2]

So the rows in sheet1 will get color coded by checking the respective A column on sheet2. For example: if the cell A2 says ABC I want the macro to fill out every cell in row 2 which has a value with the color yellow (as you can see in F1:G3 in sheet2, ABC means yellow color).

So in the end it should look something like this:

[image: What I want]

I have tried to write some code to do it unfortunately it didn't work. Nevertheless, you can take a look at it maybe it helps you help me.

```
Sub colormatching()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim aCol As Long
Dim MaxRowList As Long, destiny_row As Long, x As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

aCol = 1
MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, aCol).End(xlUp).Row


destiny_row = 1
For x = 2 To MaxRowList
    If InStr(1, wsTarget.Cells(x, 1), "ABC") > 0 Then
        wsSource.Range("$A$" & x).Select
        With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
destiny_row = destiny_row + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I would be really thankful for help on this one! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with a conditional formatting rule? Surely the color legend does not change that frequently.

Comment: @Jeeped Are you referring to matching with standard excel formulas? I don't see how that would be possible...

Comment: I can't help telling I avoid conditional formatting as much as I can, since it tends to make the workbook big and gets eventually spread all over the place by user copying&pasting, eventually loosing control. i posted a VBA solution

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone '<--| clear preceeding cells coloring
        For Each cell In Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow)
            cell.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.ColorIndex = GetColorIndex(cell.row)
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetColorIndex(rowIndex As Long) As Variant    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        GetColorIndex = .Range("F1:F3").Find(what:=.Cells(rowIndex, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
    End With
End Function
```